# Using UPawnMovementComponent to control a Pawn with Keyboard sharing code between Pawns

Tags: c++, movement, unreal-4, keyboard

I've just started to learn Unreal and reading the tutorial [Components and Collisions](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/ProgrammingAndScripting/ProgrammingWithCPP/CPPTutorials/Components/index.html) I have found that they use the `UPawnMovementComponent` to control their `Pawn`.

Before reading this tutorial I have added the code to move the Pawn inside its C++ code:

```
#include "Paddle.h"
#include "Components/BoxComponent.h"
#include "Components/StaticMeshComponent.h"

// Sets default values
APaddle::APaddle()
{
    // Set this pawn to call Tick() every frame.  You can turn this off to improve performance if you don't need it.
    PrimaryActorTick.bCanEverTick = true;

    // Set this pawn to be controlled by the lowest-numbered player
    AutoPossessPlayer = EAutoReceiveInput::Player0;

    VisualComponent = CreateDefaultSubobject<UStaticMeshComponent>(TEXT("VisualComp"));
    RootComponent = VisualComponent;

    // Removed for brevety

    CurrentVelocity.Z = 0.0f;

}

// Called when the game starts or when spawned
void APaddle::BeginPlay()
{
    Super::BeginPlay();
    
}

// Called every frame
void APaddle::Tick(float DeltaTime)
{
    Super::Tick(DeltaTime);

    // Handle movement based on our "MoveZ" axis.
    if (!CurrentVelocity.IsZero())
    {
        const FVector NewLocation = GetActorLocation() + (CurrentVelocity * DeltaTime);
        SetActorLocation(NewLocation);
    }

}

// Called to bind functionality to input
void APaddle::SetupPlayerInputComponent(UInputComponent* PlayerInputComponent)
{
    Super::SetupPlayerInputComponent(PlayerInputComponent);

    // Respond every frame to the values of our movement.
    InputComponent->BindAxis(TEXT("MovePaddle"), this, &APaddle::Move_ZAxis);
}

void APaddle::Move_ZAxis(float AxisValue)
{
    CurrentVelocity.Z = FMath::Clamp(AxisValue, -1.0f, 1.0f) * 100.0f;
}
```

A **Tip** from that tutorial says:

*Pawn Movement Components have some powerful, built-in features to help with common physics functionality, and are **a good way to share movement code between many Pawn** types. Using Components to **separate functionality is a good practice to reduce clutter** as your project grows and your Pawns become more complex.*

They say that using `Pawn Movement Components` is a good way to share movement code between many Pawn but they have the same code than me inside their Pawn component:

```
// Copyright 1998-2018 Epic Games, Inc. All Rights Reserved.

#include "CollidingPawn.h"
#include "CollidingPawnMovementComponent.h"
#include "UObject/ConstructorHelpers.h"
#include "Particles/ParticleSystemComponent.h"
#include "Components/SphereComponent.h"
#include "Camera/CameraComponent.h"
#include "GameFramework/SpringArmComponent.h"

// Sets default values
ACollidingPawn::ACollidingPawn()
{
    // Set this pawn to call Tick() every frame.  You can turn this off to improve performance if you don't need it.
    PrimaryActorTick.bCanEverTick = true;

    // Removed for brevety

    // Take control of the default player
    AutoPossessPlayer = EAutoReceiveInput::Player0;

    // Create an instance of our movement component, and tell it to update our root component.
    OurMovementComponent = CreateDefaultSubobject<UCollidingPawnMovementComponent>(TEXT("CustomMovementComponent"));
    OurMovementComponent->UpdatedComponent = RootComponent;
}

// Called when the game starts or when spawned
void ACollidingPawn::BeginPlay()
{
    Super::BeginPlay();

}

// Called every frame
void ACollidingPawn::Tick( float DeltaTime )
{
    Super::Tick( DeltaTime );

}

// Called to bind functionality to input
void ACollidingPawn::SetupPlayerInputComponent(class UInputComponent* InInputComponent)
{
    Super::SetupPlayerInputComponent(InInputComponent);

    InInputComponent->BindAction("ParticleToggle", IE_Pressed, this, &ACollidingPawn::ParticleToggle);

    InInputComponent->BindAxis("MoveForward", this, &ACollidingPawn::MoveForward);
    InInputComponent->BindAxis("MoveRight", this, &ACollidingPawn::MoveRight);
    InInputComponent->BindAxis("Turn", this, &ACollidingPawn::Turn);
}

UPawnMovementComponent* ACollidingPawn::GetMovementComponent() const
{
    return OurMovementComponent;
}

void ACollidingPawn::MoveForward(float AxisValue)
{
    if (OurMovementComponent && (OurMovementComponent->UpdatedComponent == RootComponent))
    {
        OurMovementComponent->AddInputVector(GetActorForwardVector() * AxisValue);
    }
}

void ACollidingPawn::MoveRight(float AxisValue)
{
    if (OurMovementComponent && (OurMovementComponent->UpdatedComponent == RootComponent))
    {
        OurMovementComponent->AddInputVector(GetActorRightVector() * AxisValue);
    }
}

void ACollidingPawn::Turn(float AxisValue)
{
    FRotator NewRotation = GetActorRotation();
    NewRotation.Yaw += AxisValue;
    SetActorRotation(NewRotation);
}

void ACollidingPawn::ParticleToggle()
{
    if (OurParticleSystem && OurParticleSystem->Template)
    {
        OurParticleSystem->ToggleActive();
    }
}
```

They have the same `SetupPlayerInputComponent` method and also three methods to move the Pawn inside the Pawn class. I don't know how they are going to share move code between Pawn if the code is inside each Pawn and how we can separate functionality if all the movement code is inside the Pawns.

How can I use `UPawnMovementComponent` to control a Pawn with Keyboard sharing that code with other Pawns?

Answer (score 0):

A UPawnMovementComponent is a class, from which you create your own custom movement component.  You can't call it directly to move anything.

What this means is you can assign that custom movement component you made to as many actors as you want and have them move them.